# ArrayFormula and expanding range in SUMPRODUCT

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I would like to create a tracking number in a Google Forms report. This will be an array formula that calculates the number of incidents and counts them yearly, monthly, and per type (Row N). For the most part, I already created the formula but it only works if it is dragged-down since the range in the formula is dynamic.

Here is the sample [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1erqPRraEiRisCcMNB_Ks4Yw0Y_koErIWNS8gHRbBgGo/edit?usp=sharing).

The desired result is in Column Y (dragged down formula). The array formula result is in column Z and only outputs on total value in the portions with the expanding range.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK($B$2:$B),IFERROR(1/0),YEAR(B2:B) & "-" & 
SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR($B$2:B2)=YEAR(B2:B))) & "-" & MONTH(B2:B) & 
JOIN("",ArrayFormula(left(split(N2," "),1))) & IFS(COUNTIF(N2:N,"M*"),SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($N$2:N,1)="M"),--(YEAR($B$2:$B)=YEAR(B2:B)),--(MONTH($B$2:$B)=MONTH(B2:B))),
COUNTIF(N2:N,"F*"),SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($N$2:N,1)="F"),--(YEAR($B$2:$B)=YEAR(B2:B)),--(MONTH($B$2:$B)=MONTH(B2:B))),
COUNTIF(N2:N,"P*"),SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($N$2:N,1)="P"),--(YEAR($B$2:$B)=YEAR(B2:B)),--(MONTH($B$2:$B)=MONTH(B2:B))),
COUNTIF(N2:N,"I*"),SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($N$2:N,1)="I"),--(YEAR($B$2:$B)=YEAR(B2:B)),--(MONTH($B$2:$B)=MONTH(B2:B))),
COUNTIF(N2:N,"E*"),SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($N$2:N,1)="E"),--(YEAR($B$2:$B)=YEAR(B2:B)),--(MONTH($B$2:$B)=MONTH(B2:B))))))
```

Comment: can you please add to the question what results are you getting and what is should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tracking numbers seem pretty complex, and it is unclear what particular benefit there is in encoding per-year and per-month ordinal numbers and totals in it. A simple sequence of integers would probably be easier.

To answer your question, try this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( not(isnumber(B2:B)), iferror(1/0), 
  year(B2:B) 
  & "-" & 
  countifs( 
    row(B2:B), "<=" & row(B2:B), 
    year(B2:B), year(B2:B) 
  ) 
  & "-" & 
  month(B2:B) 
  & 
  regexreplace( 
    regexreplace(N2:N, "(?i)\b([a-z])[a-z]+", "$1"), 
    "(?i)\s+|[^a-z].*", "" 
  ) 
  & 
  countifs( 
    row(B2:B), "<=" & row(B2:B), 
    year(B2:B), year(B2:B), 
    month(B2:B), month(B2:B), 
    regexextract(N2:N, "(?i)^[a-z]+"), 
    regexextract(N2:N, "(?i)^[a-z]+") 
  ) 
) )
```

The results from this array formula match the expected results you show in the sample spreadsheet.

**Note**: the tracking number format you requested contains a field with the total aggregate number of cases in a particular month that match an incident type. This means that *every* tracking number of a particular incident type in a particular month will change *every* time another incident of that type is added in that month. In other words, your tracking numbers are not "static" or "permanent".

As said, I would recommend using another tracking number format, such as a  simple sequence of integers. To make the tracking numbers permanent so that they never change, regardless of whether the incident is later edited, you will need a triggered script such as the [insertUniqueId_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95223516?msgid=96190885) script.

If you need help implementing a script, please post a new question.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'm not familiar with Reg Expressions commands, so I will study the the syntax and formula you provided.